# How can I use label studio to annotate text data in google colab?

Tags: nlp, label-studio

How can I use label studio to annotate text data in google colab? And please also suggest good alternatives to label studio which I can easily used in google colab to annotate/label text data?

I tried installing label studio in google colab but unable to launch the server.

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ac6B9qSGsBpQC1IYdcLZ96ffEy4MJ8hC?usp=sharing) is my colab notebook.